# specify custom CodeDeployServiceRole role to CodeDeployHook in aws sam DeploymentPreference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm implementing PreTrafficHook validation lambda function and want to use pre-created CodeDeployServiceRole but AWS SAM is attempting to create new role arn:aws:iam:::role/-CodeDeployServiceRole-.

I've found a related issue here https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/1496 , so looks like it's a bug. But anyway is there a way to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get around this by removing "Enabled: false" in DeploymentPreference of my preTrafficHook function resource in sam template